# Simulate onclick on a img

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to simulate a `onclick` function on all images in a page.
the problem is each img has a unique `onclick` call and also the img does not have an ID or class.

Each img is within a div:

```
<div id="339949822">
<img src="button.png" onclick="addUser('339949822');">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post more of your HTML so we can see the parent elements and figure out the best method of selecting the image.

Comment: c-smile solution works flawless. Thank you

Comment: Fair enough, don't forget to upvote and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery:

```
$("img[onclick]").each(function(index, element){
  eval( $(element).attr("onclick") );
});
```

Comment: eval works, but is not a strong solution in this case. http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Answer (score 1):

you could either add a custom attribute to the img tag

```
<img src="button.png" data-user-id="339949822"/>
```

Then reference that attribute in the event handler (you'll have the element) via

```
element.attr("data-user-id")
```

or you could traverse up the DOM and grab the id from the enclosing div.

Comment: or `element.data('user-id')`

Comment: good deal... It's been a while since I've used jQuery... didn't know they added .data!